# ¿Cómo corregir este error con seewave y tuneR?

Tags: r

Tengo un script que utiliza los paquetes seewave y tuneR pero R me devuelve el msj de que el archivo de audio no existe

```
> .libPaths("C:/R/win-library/3.2")
> require(seewave)
> require(tuneR)
> x<- readWave("L_bufonius385-389fig.wav")
Error in readWave("L_bufonius385-389fig.wav") : 
  File 'L_bufonius385-389fig.wav' does not exist.
```

Comment: ¿Estás trabajando en la misma carpeta dónde se encuentran alojados los datos? Sino, cambia el directorio de trabajo con `setwd('ruta/a/archivos')`

Comment: Revisa con `getwd()`, en esa carpeta debería estar el archivo `L_bufonius385-389fig.wav`